# PL/SQL: INSTR(), SUBSTR(), How to extract values from multi-select-list

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Following situation is given:
The tables orders o and products p are connected via multi-select-list.

products p:

- Primary key PRODUCT_ID something like "101"
- stores purchasing price like "9.25"

orders o:

- Primary key ORDER_ID something like "123456"
- stores all included products in one column named prod like ":101:199:250:999:"
- stores all included unit prices in a column named prices like ":10.0:25.0:30.5:125.25:"

So for example in order 123456 there are four products included. Product with id 101 was sold for `10.0$` (while purchasing price is `9.25$`), Product with id 199 was sold for `25.0$` and so on...

So the most challenging part for me is to extract the values needed from the multiselect list.

How can I extract the prices dependent on the ordered products to answer question like "What is the average price of sale for product with id = 999?"

I already tried something like:

```
SELECT MOD(INSTR(o.products, ':999:'),3)  FROM orders o;
```

to return the position of the value.

Since I am not a `PL/SQL` programmer I do not know how to continue on this issue...
ideas welcome.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing multiple, delimited values in a single column in the first place. Read up on database normalization

Comment: Yeah I know about this....It would be more efficient to use a third table with the keys of order_id and product_id. Nevertheless the solution should be based on the multiselect list....:-/

Comment: This will not work. I'm sure that the clever folks on this can provide some functional code that will work; but once you try to scale the system, it will be problematic. So the real answer is to fix the design.

Comment: Please tell me this is a school assignment and not a system that's in production somewhere

Comment: @APC if it is in production somewhere, it won't be for long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query below in your larger query. Or you can use it to normalize your data, once and for all. Or for both.

You are assuming the responsibility for the two colon-separated strings having the same number of tokens, etc. (which is one of the 100+ reasons to have tables in normal form in the first place).

```
with
     orders ( order_id, prod, prices ) as (
       select 123456, ':101:99:250:999:', ':10.0:25.0:30.5:125.25:' from dual union all
       select 1003  , ':101:999:'       , ':9.95:130.40:'           from dual
     )
select order_id,
       to_number(substr(prod, instr(prod, ':', 1, level) + 1, 
             instr(prod, ':', 1, level + 1) - instr(prod, ':', 1, level) - 1)) as prod_id,
       to_number(substr(prices, instr(prices, ':', 1, level) + 1, 
             instr(prices, ':', 1, level + 1) - instr(prices, ':', 1, level) - 1)) as price
from   orders
connect by level <= length(prod) - length(replace(prod, ':')) - 1
       and prior order_id = order_id
       and prior sys_guid() is not null
;

ORDER_ID  PROD_ID   PRICE
--------  -------  ------
    1003      101    9.95
    1003      999    30.4
  123456      101      10
  123456       99      25
  123456      250    30.5
  123456      999  125.25
```